# Losing data in custom point type after boost buffer call

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

i have my own type of point

```
class LocationWayPoint
{
    public:
        latlong_container location;
        WORD index;
        PWeakBasicStation station;      
};

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS(LocationWayPoint, 2, double, cs::cartesian)

    template<> struct access<LocationWayPoint, 0> {
        static inline double get(LocationWayPoint const& p) {return p.location.longitude; }
        static inline void set(LocationWayPoint& p, double const& value) {p.location.longitude = value; }
    };
    template<> struct access<LocationWayPoint, 1> {
        static inline double get(LocationWayPoint const& p) {return p.location.latitude; }
        static inline void set(LocationWayPoint& p, double const& value) {p.location.latitude = value; }
    };
}}}
typedef bg::model::linestring<LocationWayPoint> location_linestring_t;
```

....

```
location_linestring_t ls1;
```

i full this point like this (in loop)

```
LocationWayPoint point;
/* point.index = counter;            */
point.index = 7777;         
point.location.longitude = (lo_type == mongo::NumberDouble) ? point_record.getField("lo").Double() : std::atof(point_record.getField("lo").String().c_str());
point.location.latitude = (lo_type == mongo::NumberDouble) ? point_record.getField("lat").Double() : std::atof(point_record.getField("lat").String().c_str());
 ls1.push_back(point);
```

when i using ls1.push_back(point); i can access to index value

```
LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(logger,  "LocationWay::LoaderWay in " << bg::get<0>(ls1[0]) << " d2 "  << bg::get<1>(ls1[0]) << " index "<< ls1[0].index);

out = DEBUG - LocationWay::LoaderWay in xxx d2 xxx index 7777
```

but when i call replace push_back method to

```
bg::append(ls1, point);
```

i see

```
DEBUG - LocationWay::LoaderWay in xxx d2 xxx index 17 <--uninit value
```

also when i call to bg::buffer

```
boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<location_polygon_t> result; 

    boost::geometry::buffer(ls1, result,
                distance_strategy, side_strategy,
                join_strategy, end_strategy, circle_strategy);
```

any values without location sets to uninitialized (

Answer (score 2):

I think you've diagnosed the problem directly: using the algorithm "loses" attached external information for the simple reason that the points created are *new points*.

Incidentally, it's a good reason to initialize all member data - even in POD structs.

So underlying your question seems to be the *assumption* that the buffer algorithm somehow keeps the original points - just moving them and keeping the rest of their contained values. The assumption is not correct.

I can speculate as to the reason why: perhaps it is to accomodate custom geometry models that use shared points/geometries and (hence?) immutable data.

### Documentation Support

The documentation doesn't directly describe this (as being a) limitation. But that's the key point: it not describing anything about point concepts that allows for/deals with extraneous data is a sure sign that the library doesn't deal with. Here's the [Point Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_point.html), for example:

[image]

Note how it *does* have `traits::access` but it has no *concept* of cloning a point (to include extraneous data?).

Comment: Thank you for explanation!
In this case i do not see meaning to use macros like  BOOST_GEOMETRY_DETAIL_SPECIALIZE_POINT_TRAITS
to rewrite point classes

Comment: That's ok. I do, hope that's ok with you too :)