# How to extend boost geometry union_ strategy to handle own polygon type with additional data?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I've created an application with boost geometry which defines an own polygon type
with some additional data called

```
struct taggedPolygon_t : bg::model::polygon<point_t>
{
    taggedPolygon_t() {}    
    std::string mask_;
};
```

Which carries some additional information.

What I want to achieve is the boost::geometry::union_ also handles this additional
data. In my sample case it would be sufficient if member "mask" is unified like this
or similar

```
resultPoly.mask = poly1.mask + poly2.mask;
```

I tried to create a sample application - but it's at the limits of Coliru.

I think everyone should get the idea?

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using point_t = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>;

struct taggedPolygon_t : bg::model::polygon<point_t>
{
    taggedPolygon_t() {}    
    std::string mask_;
};

namespace boost::geometry::traits
{
    template<> struct tag<taggedPolygon_t> { typedef polygon_tag type; };
    template<> struct ring_const_type<taggedPolygon_t> { typedef const bg::model::polygon<point_t>::ring_type& type; };
    template<> struct ring_mutable_type<taggedPolygon_t> { typedef bg::model::polygon<point_t>::ring_type& type; };
    template<> struct interior_const_type<taggedPolygon_t> { typedef const bg::model::polygon<point_t>::inner_container_type& type; };
    template<> struct interior_mutable_type<taggedPolygon_t> { typedef bg::model::polygon<point_t>::inner_container_type& type; };

    template<> struct exterior_ring<taggedPolygon_t>
    {
        static bg::model::polygon<point_t>::ring_type& get(bg::model::polygon<point_t>& p) {return p.outer(); }
        static bg::model::polygon<point_t>::ring_type const& get(bg::model::polygon<point_t> const& p) {return p.outer(); }
    };

    template<> struct interior_rings<taggedPolygon_t>
    {
        static bg::model::polygon<point_t>::inner_container_type& get(bg::model::polygon<point_t>& p) {return p.inners(); }
        static bg::model::polygon<point_t>::inner_container_type const& get(bg::model::polygon<point_t> const& p) {return p.inners(); }
    };
} // namespace boost::geometry::traits

using multiTaggedPolygon_t = bg::model::multi_polygon<taggedPolygon_t>;

int main() {
    multiTaggedPolygon_t polygons;
    bg::read_wkt("MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), "
        "((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35),"
        "(30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))", polygons);

    std::string reason;
    if (!bg::is_valid(polygons, reason)) {
        std::cout << "Correcting data: " << reason << "\n";
        bg::correct(polygons);
    }
    
    multiTaggedPolygon_t separated(std::move(polygons));
    
    multiTaggedPolygon_t newPolygons;
    for (auto& poly : separated)
    {
        // Unify polygons
        bg::union_(polygons, poly, newPolygons);
        std::swap(polygons, newPolygons);
        newPolygons.clear();
    }

    for (auto& p : polygons)
        std::cout << p.mask_ << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff15c25e4d672ebd

I thought that the strategies() parameter of the union_ function would be
the way to go but I'm stuck as there seems to be no specific documentation
for this case?

Comment: The only datastructure in Boost Geometry I'm aware of that allows for "indexable types" (where the indexable can be used to point at more data) is `boost::geometry::indexing::rtree`. Here's a nice example https://stackoverflow.com/q/66889783/85371, perhaps it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is frequently requested, sad thing is due to the concepts there is no way to piggy-back meta data in geometry entities (specifically, points).

Points are default constructible, and are assigned coordinates using the accessor functions.

This is important for the generic case: if the output geometry has an entirely different types. Yes, specially for `union_` you might expect some input points to be *copy-constructed*, but alas.

I've previosly explained this in some more detail here:

- [Losing data in custom point type after boost buffer call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676309/losing-data-in-custom-point-type-after-boost-buffer-call/46676375#46676375)

Comment: This is IMHO a design shortcoming that could have been avoided. A library should not default-construct user-provided types. It should use a user-provided factory instead.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It would be easy for me to agree. However, do realize that this is large part a result of the algorithms themselves, which are standard specified (DE9IM and OGC Simple Feature Specification, from memory). In fact, a factory wouldn't help at all because the factory wouldn't have the state either. The algorithm would still need to supply the factory with the metadata. And there is the real problem: for many algorithms there will not be a sensible semantic to use.

Comment: What if the meta-data is not copyable? Then we need cloning. What if clones are contradictory (e.g. cloning breaks object identity, so you could end up with nonsense anyways). I would agree that _maybe_ in the case of `union_` it may be safe to assume some simple semantics (like, resultant points take metatdata copied from the respective source points). But there will be inevitable problems like: extra points for intersections that have no corresponding source, and points that are duplicate in the input geometries. I don't think the choice is that weird or problematic after all.

Comment: I agree that this is not simple. Copying is the user's problem, the algorithms would pass metadata by reference. Which metadata to pass is the real issue. Maybe for each created geometry, a list of source geometries and the reason why the new geometry is created (intersection, transformation, whatever).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I know Boost Geometry is taking GSoC project - perhaps they'll even accept ideas. I think you appreciate the conundrums. If you can pitch it, I can testify that it is a recurring wish by users.

Comment: I tried to trace a call to union_ in order to find the location where a polygon is actually merged to the multipoly. In my test case I even used a multipolygon with 2 separate polys which would result in ONE poly after the merge. TL;DR: I didn't have much success... at least it was not obvious where I should place some kind of "merge" for the additional data.

Comment: I remember doing the same back in ~2017 with the other answer

Comment: It calms me down that I'm not the only one getting stuck here. Maybe BG will get some update one fine day... though I do not have much hope. But who knows? @sehe: Thanks for your valuable support.